# Android: What is the best way to design attached image for all different screen sizes?

Tags: android

I am working on a game which will support multiple devices and I have a start screen. I have attached one image for the same. As in image there are three different text (Start, help, About us) for this I take three different buttons and adjust them according to text and make them invisible to make text clickable. But it works only for a specific screen and I cant be able to find a way to make it for multiple screens. I have alo attached my xml layout code which I have created for this. Please help me to solve this out...[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/start_screen" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
    android:background="#00000000" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#00000000" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:background="#00000000" />
```

Comment: Maybe you could detach the ship image along with that text in another layout container and place the `Buttons` relative to that container. Then place the ship image container in the bigger picture in the center.

Comment: sorry, but did not get your point can you please explain it..

Comment: The idea is to have two images, the sea and the land as the background(and you'll have an image for various sizes/densities). The ship(and only the ship) along with the texts will be in a container as the background. Knowing the dimension of the ship image you could easily place the Buttons at precise coordinates(but you'll need to calculate them for the various density images). Then you'll place the ship image on the background image in the center and it should stay in place.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I got your point, but how can I calculate the coordinates to place the buttons is there any code or link available for the better understanding.

Comment: I don't have any links to recommend. You basically calculate the positions like you already did, but you need to do it for each of your image density version. You'll probably need to set those position on the Buttons, at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "resource qualifiers" in your res directory to provide different graphics for different screen sizes / densities.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

Comment: yes I am using all this stuff but the problem is, according to android all 3.2 to 4.6 inch screen phones comes in layout-normal category, if I adjust my buttons according to 3.2 inch screen and run my application on 4.6 inch screen device buttons are not properly aligned.